# Generate a random distribution by group conditional on a column

Tags: r, if-statement, random, aggregate, sampling

I want to generate two different distributions conditional on a column. For example, here I am generating a normal distribution `rnorm()` if `z1` is above 25 and a Poisson `rpois()` otherwise. Additionally, I would like to get variation by groups(column `id`) from the stated distribution.

For now I have the following code:

```
df <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
                      4L, 4L), z1 = c(21L, 21L, 21L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 
                                      20L, 20L, 20L)), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = "data.frame")  
  
df$sample  <- with(df, ifelse(z1 > 25, 
                         rnorm(n = 1,mean = 0,sd = 1), ##Normal(0,1)
                         rpois(n = 1,lambda = 5)))     ## Poisson(5) 

  # id z1     sample
  # 1   1 21  6.0000000
  # 2   1 21  6.0000000
  # 3   1 21  6.0000000
  # 4   2 28 -0.8036847
  # 5   2 28 -0.8036847
  # 6   2 28 -0.8036847
  # 7   3 30 -0.8036847
  # 8   3 30 -0.8036847
  # 9   3 30 -0.8036847
  # 10  4 20  6.0000000
  # 11  4 20  6.0000000
  # 12  4 20  6.0000000
```

Unfortunately, as you can see above **I do not get variation within groups of ids** (column `id`).
Below is my desired output in the column `desired_sample`.

```
  
  #     id z1     sample     desired_sample
  # 1   1 21  6.0000000  5.0000000
  # 2   1 21  6.0000000  5.0000000
  # 3   1 21  6.0000000  5.0000000
  # 4   2 28 -0.8036847  0.7356226
  # 5   2 28 -0.8036847  0.7356226
  # 6   2 28 -0.8036847  0.7356226
  # 7   3 30 -0.8036847 -1.359669
  # 8   3 30 -0.8036847 -1.359669
  # 9   3 30 -0.8036847 -1.359669
  # 10  4 20  6.0000000  4.0000000
  # 11  4 20  6.0000000  4.0000000
  # 12  4 20  6.0000000  4.0000000
```

[**Follow up**]

The following code does it, but...

```
con_dist2 <- function(x){
  ifelse( x>=25,
          return(rnorm(1,mean = 0 , sd = 1 )),
          return(rpois(1,lambda = 5 )))
}

df$desired_sample2<- with(df ,ave(x = z1, id, FUN = con_dist2), )
```

... is there any way to include the threshold value (`25`) as a function `con_dist2` input to make it more flexible and reusable?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I will edit my question. I meant _I do not get variation **within** group of ids (column id)_. To be even more precise, I want that withing each segment (that is defined by `z1>25` and `z1<=25`)  the values are different draws from the same distribution (which is different for each segment). Does it make sense now?

Comment: Try this first this function `myfun <- function(x)
{
  y <- ifelse(x > 25,rnorm(n = 1,mean = 0,sd = 1),rpois(n = 1,lambda = 5))
  return(y)
}
` and then this code: `df$Sample <- apply(df['z1'],1,myfun)`

Comment: Thank you a lot @Duck, I just posted a follow up with a very very similar structure as the one you proposed. Lastly, is there any way to include the threshold value (`25`) as an input of `myfun` to make it more flexible and reusable?

Comment: I have added a possible solution for the new statement. Let me know if that works for you. You have to add a new parameter in the function.

Comment: That was exactly what I needed, thank you!! I could not find it in the documentation, but is there any limit for the number of extra arguments that I can pass to the `ave` function?

Comment: It would be better if you add the n parameters to the function, then you can only continue adding inside the `ave()` as we did!

Comment: I have added an example with another parameter so that you can see how it works. I hope that can be helpful for you. And if the answer helped you consider potentially accepting it. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this change on your code:

```
#Function
con_dist2 <- function(x,n){
  ifelse( x>=n,
          return(rnorm(1,mean = 0 , sd = 1 )),
          return(rpois(1,lambda = 5 )))
}
#Apply
df$desired_sample2<- with(df ,ave(x = z1, id, FUN = function(x) con_dist2(x,n=25)) )
```

For more parameters try this:

```
#Function 2
con_dist2 <- function(x,n,mymean){
  ifelse( x>=n,
          return(rnorm(1,mean = mymean , sd = 1 )),
          return(rpois(1,lambda = 5 )))
}
#Apply 2
df$desired_sample2<- with(df ,ave(x = z1, id, FUN = function(x) con_dist2(x,n=25,mymean = 0)) )
```